# Menu options not working on Android 2.2 and 2.3.5

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I'm having a problem with my android devices running 2.2 and 2.3.5. versions. I have been developing a simple app and have had no problems with any of my code so far. Since my last test the menu items have stopped loading up other Activities/running Intents on click and I really don't know why as I have reloaded my bin/gen folders, re-built the project, cleaned it but to no cigar! I've included the classes in my app and the android manifest for clarity.

**Main Activity containing the Intents for app navigation**

```
package rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class CrowdSnapCymru extends Activity {

    MenuItem item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crowd_snap_cymru);
    }

    /**
     * Empty constructor for CrowdSnapCymru
     */
    public CrowdSnapCymru() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(){
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {   
            case R.id.app_camera:
                Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, SnapCamera.class);
                startActivity(firstIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.app_dataentry:
                Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, DataEntry.class);
                startActivity(secondIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.app_upload:
                Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(this, UploadRecord.class);
                startActivity(thirdIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.app_home:
                Intent fourthIntent = new Intent(this, ImageSelector.class);
                startActivity(fourthIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.app_about:
                Intent fifthIntent = new Intent(this, CrowdSnapCymru.class);
                startActivity(fifthIntent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**Another Activity which makes use of the original intent code**

```
package rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class UploadRecord extends CrowdSnapCymru {

    MenuItem item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_record);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void loadMenuResponses() {
        onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**ANDROID MANIFEST XML FILE AND ACTION_BAR XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.CrowdSnapCymru"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.SnapCamera"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.DataEntry"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.UploadRecord"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_record"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">        
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.ImageSelector"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_selector"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  >
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/app_camera"
      android:title="@string/Camera"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera" 
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item android:id="@+id/app_dataentry"
      android:title="@string/Edit"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

<item android:id="@+id/app_upload"
      android:title="@string/Upload"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_upload"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item android:id="@+id/app_about"
    android:title="@string/About"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Can anyone figure out the problem? The menu buttons are not loaded the intended intents. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onOptionsItemSelected()` should override

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Menu item){
switch(item.getItemId())
{   
    case R.id.app_camera:
        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, SnapCamera.class);
        startActivity(firstIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_dataentry:
        Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, DataEntry.class);
        startActivity(secondIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_upload:
        Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(this, UploadRecord.class);
        startActivity(thirdIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_home:
        Intent fourthIntent = new Intent(this, ImageSelector.class);
        startActivity(fourthIntent);
        return true;

    case R.id.app_about:
        Intent fifthIntent = new Intent(this, CrowdSnapCymru.class);
        startActivity(fifthIntent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in menu->menu.xml

Instead of android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText", use like this. android:showAsAction="always"

Hope it will work.